Generating Unique Hash Value for Entire Row Considering Null Values
I have a sample dataset and code snippet in PySpark where I'm attempting to generate a hash value for each row in a DataFrame. Here's the code I'm using:
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws, sha2, concat, hash
from datetime import datetime, date 
df = spark.createDataFrame([ 
    ("user1", "Bangalore", 'Grade1', date(2000, 8, 1)), 
    ("user2", "Delhi", 'Grade2', date(2000, 6, 2)),
    ("user3", "Delhi", 'Grade2', date(2000, 6, 2)), 
    ("user4", "Chennai", 'Grade3', date(2000, 5, 3)),
    ("user5", None, 'Grade3', date(2000, 5, 3)) ,
    ("user5", "Grade3", None, date(2000, 5, 3)),
    ("user6", "", 'Grade4', date(2000, 5, 3)) ,
    ("user6", "Grade4", "", date(2000, 5, 3)) 
], schema='userId string, city string, grade string, graduationDate date') 
  
df_hash = (
    df.withColumn(
        "_delta_hash_sha2_concat_ws", sha2(concat_ws("-", *["userId", "city", "grade", "graduationDate"]), 384)
    )
    .withColumn("_delta_hash_sha2_concat", sha2(concat("userId", "city", "grade", "graduationDate"), 256))
    .withColumn("_delta_hash_hash", hash(*["userId", "city", "grade", "graduationDate"]))
)
display(df_hash)  

Result of the dataset
In my dataset, some rows contain null values, and I prefer to retain these nulls rather than replacing them with empty strings or any other placeholder.
However, when using sha2 to generate hash values, I've noticed that rows with null values are generating the same hash.  For instance, in the case of "user5", both rows generate the same hash despite having different null placements.
Upon further inspection, it seems that sha2 is not considering the position of null values when generating hash values.  Therefore, I'm seeking suggestions on how to generate unique hash values for each row while preserving null values without replacing them. I would like to avoid using row_number to assign row IDs.
Important Note: I do not wish to replace null values with empty strings or "NULL". I aim to keep null values intact.
I appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to achieve this goal. Thank you!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I understand that you don't want to replace null for permanent. What about just replacing it for the creation of the hash?

@ChenHirsh, yes i have implemented that using coalesce, but i would avoid that to do as  i want logic to be based on the table data

@ganeshacharya I think you will have to replace the null values if the hash algorithm ignore them

replace null with string "null" ?

You can build a CSV string from the 4 columns and call sha2 on it:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("user1", "Bangalore", 'Grade1', date(2000, 8, 1)),
    ("user2", "Delhi", 'Grade2', date(2000, 6, 2)),
    ("user3", "Delhi", 'Grade2', date(2000, 6, 2)),
    ("user4", "Chennai", 'Grade3', date(2000, 5, 3)),
    ("user5", None, 'Grade3', date(2000, 5, 3)),
    ("user5", "Grade3", None, date(2000, 5, 3)),
    ("user6", "", 'Grade4', date(2000, 5, 3)),
    ("user6", "Grade4", "", date(2000, 5, 3))
], schema='userId string, city string, grade string, graduationDate date')

csv_row = F.to_csv(F.struct(*df.columns))
df_hash = df.withColumn('new_hash', F.sha2(csv_row, 256))
df_hash.show(10, False)

# +------+---------+------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
# |userId|city     |grade |graduationDate|new_hash                                                        |
# +------+---------+------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
# |user1 |Bangalore|Grade1|2000-08-01    |0fbb6b79b59625c4456ce977a10ba0f0733458a9b2a92a4279d47938bf1aa80a|
# |user2 |Delhi    |Grade2|2000-06-02    |63304ebd30ac4e23288f656087525585ea5815b5ec4b44ee70c0ffbf98cac71d|
# |user3 |Delhi    |Grade2|2000-06-02    |e3f6d69ebda4c96439fb06fc2673ce40455ff07e6e2bf16a5cb209b82d82c739|
# |user4 |Chennai  |Grade3|2000-05-03    |2ca896ea1fcfc8abee6b6505cbe443751498f37dc0420779deec70c3bdf9d8a0|
# |user5 |null     |Grade3|2000-05-03    |f7bd9377bb3e1bbf854e1696584d721045edf0f3cb7da4597aec871f556a81ee|
# |user5 |Grade3   |null  |2000-05-03    |132fb03e23a680c7b8d2c64e1c917826c4918761c1338149874ce2de0cccf1fb|
# |user6 |         |Grade4|2000-05-03    |f57d3844dfc0f1a3ba9084f1d77d927d446e9ca55a88a627ec98ec89ee960d94|
# |user6 |Grade4   |      |2000-05-03    |ec09ecec83543c0a76f9b568698496bcdd378589d7bcc9ad69a669cb99041001|
# +------+---------+------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+


